# subprocess.call runs successfully but check_output fails due to exit status of the program being run

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following:

```
subprocess.call(['trufflehog', '/Users/myuser/workspace/somedir']) #this works
subprocess.check_output(['trufflehog', '/Users/myuser/workspace/somedir']) #this fails

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['trufflehog', '/Users/myuser/workspace/somedir']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

For some reasons check_output fails but call works fine. But the problem with .call is that it doesn't actually keep my output, it just prints it to stdout and returns a status code. How can I get trufflehog's output?

Comment: Can you run the command in bash: `$ trufflehog /Users/myuser/workspace/somedir` Then get the exit code: `echo $?` Also try usign `communicate` or `Popen`

Comment: Hmm I'm getting

echo $
$

for the exit code

Comment: `$$` is the PID of your current shell. `$?` is the exit code of the last command. `trufflehog` is reporting that it failed by returning a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://github.com/dxa4481/truffleHog/issues/87

Trufflehog returns exit code `1` when it finds secrets and `0` when it finds nothing, AKA "Clean Code". I assume they want you to be able to run this command over many directories / repos and fail as soon as it finds secrets.

If you want the output of the command, you can do:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.Popen(['trufflehog', '/Users/myuser/workspace/somedir'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print(output)
```

*Be sure to understand the security implications of `shell=True`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid shell=True